# Releasing mouse from textarea to on document calling click event in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, dom-events

When I'm trying to select text from textarea through mouse and releasing the mouse on a document it calling the click event on Chrome browser but when I'm doing same on Firefox and IE the event is not getting called.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
     console.log("click event", e);
});
```

Like other browsers I want to prevent it to get fired on chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is your question then? Which way you'd like to get the event triggered?

Comment: Actually dragging from a textarea to the body and releasing the mouse button [triggers click also in FF](https://jsfiddle.net/su7r23xe/).

Comment: My question is why it is occuring in chrome and not in other browsers. Is there any way that it shouldn't get called on chrome

Comment: Well, it's a click event on the document, I can't see why it should be prevented? And as said above, the same happen in FireFox too.

Comment: Well but in my case it not firing on firefox and ie

Comment: Then you've some other events preventing bubbling.